# Splitting by newlines

Tags: bash

Have been using different bash function implementations that is able to process separate lines in arguments.

```
var1="
First Argument
A new line"

var2="
Second Argument
A new line"
```

Calling the function as

```
theone $var
```

to disallow word splitting.

But then inside the function, I still have to to quote `$@`.

```
theone ()
 {
  for vl in "$@"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$vl"
  done
 }
```

What I want is to split by newline.

Comment: This sounds very similar to your earlier [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735787/processing-a-multiline-variable-line-by-line-within-a-bash-function). Doesn't the technique answered there also work here?

Comment: The focus of this question is about quoting.  When calling the function I do not quote the argument because I want to split the arguments by line.  But then, I am forced to quote `$@` in the internal loop, otherwise printf '%s\n' "$vl" will split by word.  This introduces some confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `theone $var` splits on every word in `$var`: the first argument is `First`, the second is `Argument`, the third is `A`, and so on. You will lose your embedded newlines with this approach, and as with any unquoted variable any word in the string that contains a shell wildcard (`*`, `[`, `]`, `?`) will be subject to globbing and matched against names in the current directory. A string such as "Are you sure??" could be expanded to "Are you surety" if you had a file called `surety` in the current directory. Generally, not a good idea.

Based on your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/735808/100397) I would suggest that's supposed to be written `theone "$var"`, where word splitting does not take place and you have a single multi-line argument to `theone`.

If you want to process each line of `$var` separately I can suggest a number of different constructs. In each, the `printf` line is written to show clearly what is being processed in the inner loop. Call each as `theone "$var"`:

1. POSIX

   ```
   theone()
   {
       printf '%s\n' "$@" |
           while IFS= read -r vl
           do
               printf '## vl: %s ##\n' "$vl"
           done
   }
   ```
2. Shells such as `bash`

   ```
   theone()
   (
       for arg in "$@"
       do
           while IFS= read -r vl
           do
               printf '## vl: %s ##\n' "$vl"
           done <<< "$arg"
       done
   )
   ```
3. Also shells such as `bash`

   ```
   theone()
   (
       for arg in "$@"
       do
           readarray -t vls <<<"$arg"

           for vl in "${vls[@]}"
           do
               printf '## vl: %s ##\n' "$vl"
           done
       done
   )
   ```

All of these can be simplified by removing the outermost loop if you really only want to pass a single (multi-line) argument. For example, the last one could be written like this:

4. Shells such as `bash`

   ```
   theone()
   {
       local vls vl

       readarray -t vls <<<"$1"

       for vl in "${vls[@]}"
       do
           printf '## vl: %s ##\n' "$vl"
       done
   }
   ```

Comment: I like versions `2` and `3` because the implementations show what is being done quite clearly.  Originally, I was focusing on passing a single argument, but can see the value of allowing multiple arguments.  What would you suggest for multiple arguments?  Would you be satisfied with version 2 ?

Comment: Is it possible that using `<<<` (reading from `stdin`) will not preserve special chars (like `newline`), causing troubles ?

Comment: I do not think that `IFS='\n'`  behaves well.  `IFS` is used for field splitting, not to determine where a record ends (there is the `-d` option).  Shouldn't `IFS` be set to the empty string instead ?

Comment: In general, which would be safer and superior ? `done < <(printf '%s\n' "$arg")` or `done <<< "$arg"` ?

Comment: I am favouring the process-substitution path.

Comment: Calling `theone $var` splits on characters of IFS and then does globbing, it does not *split on words*. With `IFS=$'\n'; set -o noglob; theone $var` it would split on sequences of one or more newlines (ignoring leading and trailing newline).